# Android Studio handle request of volley library

Tags: android, android-studio

How to handle request/response volley library, When i use method POST.

I want to set Toast when post complete.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How can i achieve it?

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, uri,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {//Body
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("participantId", editText2.getText().toString());
                params.put("name", editText3.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Create Volley
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(request);
```

Comment: Hi, Can you elaborate your question? Are you asking how to parse the response string? If you only need to trigger the Toast when complete just place it in either `onResponse` or `onErrorResponse`.

Comment: Thank for reply, I want to set Toast when i use method POST request complete.

Comment: You just need to add your Toast inside in `onResponse` assuming the request will be completed successfully similar what you did in `onErrorResponse`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. but i have a problem with api.

Comment: Have you added already the Internet permission in your manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its server response issue not code issue, you will never get called onResponse(String response), in failure case its should get called onErrorResponse() .

If your not getting callback for onErrorResponse() , you can set the timeout as below.

```
request .setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```